# how do i close the TCP session created from a linux box using a command?

Tags: java, linux, sockets

I am trying to close the TCP/IP session created from a java application using a linux command to check how application behaves. can you suggest a command from linux to do this?

Comment: Please provide the code of what you've tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: You mean other than by terminating the Java program that created the connection? Why?

Comment: Please read this post on how to ask a question on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. As it stands you have not provided enough information about what you have tried, any resources you have searched or any sample code that you are using.

Comment: Because I would like to see how application behaves if the session created by the application closed externally by some other means?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following command

```
tcpkill -i eth0 port 21
```

eth0 represents connection name and port followed by port number

For more options you can visit http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/kill-tcp-connection-using-linux-netstat.php

Comment: I am not seeing the utility tcpkill in linux machine... should i download it seperately?